# Failed to import bridging header

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode7, xcode7.3

I faced with some error, I can't compile my project because of this error:

[image]

It happened unexpectedly, so I tested my project many times, and then without any changes it starts to throw this error.

I searched using finder this path: '/Users/amatrosov/Documents/projects/Vent-Axia/Vent-Axia/Vent-Axia-Bridging-Header.h and it exist.

YMSCBCentralManager.h - also a part of my pods libraries and I can simple find it in Xcode search.

I've tried different answers on this question, like removing bridging header and re create new one, but nothing helps.

Maybe something with pods like someone suggested, I am not sure.

This is my bridging file:

[image]

Comment: delete that line from bridging header, and try update pods, it should work

Comment: @Lu_ which line should I remove?

Comment: #import YMSCBsomething.h

Comment: @Lu_ the bridging header does not contain this import line

Comment: this is not possible, something that is not there will not cause error, read error and check again, clear project or something and check again

Comment: @Lu_ YMSCBsomething.h is imported to another my .h file and I can remove it as I inherited that object form YMSCBsomething

Comment: @Lu_ this is my bridging file (I've added image). So I need to use APCCentalManager.h and .m that's why I created bridging header. APCCentralManger inherits from YMSCBsomething that show for us some error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118815/discussion-between-lu-and-matrosov-alexander).

Comment: @Lu_ looks like I had to add this file like this #import `<YmsCoreBluetooth/YMSCBCentralManager.h>` or `@import YmsCoreBluetooth;` not just `#import "YMSCBCentralManager.h"`

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander that worked for you? Odd. It should be `#import "YmsCoreBluetooth/YMSCBCentralManager.h"` Note the `""` instead of the `<>`I'm having the same issue btw, but your <> idea doesn't work for me. This is all due to a cocoapod update. Everything was fine before.

Comment: @crewshin, yea that's <> work for me or `@import`. Maybe it's connected to specific folder where YMSCBCentralManager.h is located. I am not sure.

Answer (score -1):

I once had this issue and solved it by deleting the bridging header file and creating it using XCode wizard instead of manually. Its possible that XCode generates some internal link which is not being created when you add the file manually.

See instructions on how to generate it using XCode [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).

Comment: maybe it's connected to cocoa pods? YMSCBCentralManager.h is part of pods library

Comment: It could be, try removing all pod related files and the bridging reader, after that add the bridging header using XCode and download the pods again.

Comment: looks like I had to add this file like this #import <YmsCoreBluetooth/YMSCBCentralManager.h> or @import YmsCoreBluetooth;

Comment: Great! please post the answer with the solution if it worked, so others can use it :)

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe you know if we should use this approach for all objective c files from pods.

Comment: These answers are awful.